# Can I avoid runtime raster interpolation by creating an image pyramid to match the zoom scales?

Tags: raster, gdal, scale, mapguide

For image quality and performance reasons, it would be best to perform interpolation of my large TIFF image of the world (10GB) beforehand to all the zoom scales I need to display at so that MapGuide (my map server) doesn't have to do it at run-time.

Is there a way to determine what zoom scales I should use based on the size of my image pyramids, or vice versa (I'm using GDAL for creating image pyramids)?

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar to MIP Mapping, where resolutions in powers of 2 (1024x1024, 2048x1024, etc) are typically used for optimization purposes during hardware acceleration. So if you were following that line of thinking, starting with a 1024x1024 resolution, it would go

1024x1024,
512x512,
256x256,
128x128,
64x64

and on...

There are MIP Mapping tools that do this, leaving you to only have to hand off the optimized texture map to the video card for rendering. I would imagine a custom image pyramid like you are proposing would work in a similar manner, but the blending between levels of detail is up to the mapping software or you.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, it was just a matter of figuring out how to map between scales and image resolution